# Error when using xlsx package in write.xlsx

Tags: java, r, excel

I am trying to save a file using `write.xslx` (when saving with `write.csv` some row got shift in more columns so I am trying to save the file as xlsx directly).
If I type this command:

```
    write.xlsx (old.data, file ="Documents/new.xlsx", sheetName="Sheet1",col.names=TRUE, row.names=TRUE, append=FALSE)
```

or

```
    write.xlsx (old.data, "Documents/new.xlsx", sheetName="Sheet1",col.names=TRUE, row.names=TRUE, append=FALSE)
```

I get this error:

> Error in .jnew("org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook") :
> Java Exception <no description because toString() failed>.jnew("org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook")<S4 object of class "jobjRef">

Can anyone help me sort it out?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this question can easily be answered. Is `<working_directory>/Documents` writeable to you? Can you create the file

```
write.xlsx ( data.frame( a = 1:10, row.names = letters[ 1:10 ] ), "Documents/new.xlsx", sheetName="Sheet1",col.names=TRUE, row.names=TRUE, append=FALSE)
```

If this works, but with `old.data` it doesn't you have to provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

However, I experienced every here and again weird problems with the `xlsx` package. From my experience `XLConnect` is much more robust and bug-free:

```
library("XLConnect")
writeWorksheetToFile( "Documents/newxlsx", old.data, "Sheet1", header=TRUE, rownames = "rownames.header" )
```

Comment: Thanks, the XLConnect is for the r v3 and I am using other package in v2. anyway I solve it using csv file and using as separator ";" now my file is working.thank you so much for the advice.

Comment: @user2452520 What is v3 and what is v2?

Answer (score 0):

`write_xlsx()` from the `writexl` package works great for me and is way faster! It also works fine with tibbles and does not have the annoying errors or resctrictions from the `xlsx`package. It is also completely written in C so no Java, Perl or Rtools are required.

For more info see https://ropensci.org/technotes/2017/09/08/writexl-release/

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same problem. I think there might be a bug with openXL but I love working with it. So I open and close R and then change the wd, saved the file exactly where the wd was and then I run the exact same code again. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Today I had that problem after deployment.
At this moment I didn't need to change package and stick to xlsx
I updated dplyr, xlsx, and the one that did the trick was updating rjava.
Since it was a conflict with java and xlsx calls it, I gave it a shot.

Hope this work for you too